# ODE in form $(f(x).y)'' = g(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following linear second order ODE:

(1) $\cos(x)y'' - 2\sin(x)y' - \cos(x)y = e^x$

And I noticed this can be written as:

(2) $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}y\cos(x) = e^x$

And while I feel this simplification is not a coincidence and should be used in this problem I don't know how to use formula (2) to find homogeneous and particular solutions.

Is this simplification useful for this problem or am I grasping at straws?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I suggest that you use `\cos x` and `\sin x` in order to get $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ respectively.

Comment: Just do double integration both sides and you'll get the exact solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to find homogeneous/particular solutions because you have identified that this is an exact equation. Integrating both sides with respect to $x$ twice gives
$$\cos{(x)}y=e^x+C_1x+C_2$$
$$\therefore y=\sec{(x)}(e^x+C_1x+C_2)$$

Comment: Brilliant, thankyou. When differentiating $e^x$ twice do we multiply one constant by $x$ because $e^x + C1 + C2$ is redundant?

Comment: We are integrating twice. $\int e^x\mathrm{d}x=e^x+C_1$ then $\int (e^x+C_1)\mathrm{d}x=e^x+C_1x+C_2$. When integrating both sides we only need to consider a constant on one side because the difference between two constants is just another constant.

Comment: Thankyou so much, this clears it up perfectly.